# Sort a big number of pdf files by the common part in their names with Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, sorting, filenames

I need to sort a huge (ca. 20000) amount of pdf files by the most common part in their names. The structure of each file is pretty same: `XXX_1500004898_CommonPART.pdf` (some files are delimited with "`_`" and some with "`-`")

This is the code I used for it:

```
files = []
for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(r'C:PATH/TO/FILES'):
    for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*0000*.pdf'):
             print (file)
             files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
time.sleep(2)
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: str(x.split('-')[2]))
```

But when I run it, the only thing I get is a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PATH\Sorting.py", line 14, in <module>
    sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: str(x.split('-')[2]))
  File "C:\PATH\Sorting.py", line 14, in <lambda>
    sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: str(x.split('-')[2]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm new in Python, so I may seem unexperienced, as well I still have no clue how to tell Python to create the folders by these common parts and move the files there.

Can you please help me with this issue?

Thanks a lot!

UPDATED CODE:

```
files_result = []
for root, dirnames, files in   os.walk(r'C:\PATH\TESTT'):
    for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*0000*.pdf'):
            print (file)
            files_result.append(os.path.join(root, file))
time.sleep(2)
sorted_files = sorted(file.replace("_", "-").split("-")[2] for file in files_result if (file.count("-")+file.count("_") == 2))
print (sorted_files)
```

and this is the result:

```
['ALOISE emma.pdf', 'ALOISEEMMA.pdf', 'ARETEIA.pdf', 'ASSEL.pdf', 'AVV.BELLOMI.pdf', 'BRACI E ABBRACCI.pdf', 'CERRATA D..pdf', 'CERRATA REFRIGERAZIONE.pdf', etc.....]
```

---

Here are some typical filenames:

```
ANI-150000000106SD_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000006-CENTROCHIRURGIAAMBULATORIALEsrl_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000007-EUROMED ECOLOGICA_APPROVATO.pdf
ANI-1500000008-TELECOM_APPROVATO.pdf
ANI-1500000009-TELECOM_APPROVATO.pdf
ANI-15000000100-ALOISE EMMA_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000101-centro.chirurgia.ambulatoriale_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000102-TELECOM_APPROVATO.pdf
ANI-15000000103-MCLINK_APPROVATO.pdf
ani-15000000104-idrafer.pdf
ANI-15000000105EUROMEDECOLOGICA_approvata.pdf
ANI-15000000107LAGSERVICE.pdf
ANI-15000000109TCHR_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000011-COOPSERVICEn9117011288 approvate (2).pdf
ANI-1500000011-COOPSERVICEn°9117011288.pdf
ANI-15000000110-TELECOM_APPROVATO.pdf
ANI-15000000113-SECURLAB_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000114-SECURLAB_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000115-COOPSERVICE_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000116-COOPSERVICE_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000117-REPOWER_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000118-CECCHINIlaura_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000119-DESENA_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000012-TCHRSERCICES.R.L._approvato (1).pdf
ANI-15000000121-ALOISE_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000122-LAGSERVICE.pdf
ANI-15000000123-SECURLAB_approvata.pdf
ANI-15000000125-QUERZOLA_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000129-TC HR_apprpvato.pdf
ANI-1500000013-TAV_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000130-LAGSERVICE.pdf
ANI-15000000131EUROMEDecologica_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000132-LAV.pdf
ANI-15000000133-REPOWER.pdf
ANI-15000000134-MCLINK.pdf
ANI-15000000135-COOPSERVICE_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000136-COOPSERVICE_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000138-TCHR._approvatopdf.pdf
ANI-15000000139-ALOISEEMMA.pdf
ANI-1500000014-OFFICEDEPOT_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000140_TELECOM.pdf
ANI-15000000141-CHIRURGIAAMBULATORIALE_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000142-LAG.pdf
ANI-15000000143-LAG.pdf
ANI-15000000145-TELECOM.pdf
ANI-15000000146-LAG.pdf
ANI-15000000147-WERFEN.pdf
ani-15000000148-enigas.pdf
ANI-15000000153TCHR_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000154-ASSEL.pdf
ANI-15000000155-DIGIUSEPPEgiancarlo.pdf
ANI-15000000156-SD.pdf
ANI-15000000157-SAS.pdf
ani-15000000158-energeticSOURCE.pdf
ANI-15000000159-chirurgia ambulatoriale.pdf
ANI-1500000016-THEMIX_approvato.pdf
ANI-15000000160-CERRATA REFRIGERAZIONE.pdf
ANI-15000000162-ALOISE emma.pdf
ANI-1500000017-ASSEL_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000018-QUERZOLA_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000019-BDO_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000020-THEMIXfatt_ approvato.134.pdf
ANI-1500000021-SECURLAB_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000022-LYRECO+DDT_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000023-COOPSERVICE approvato (1).pdf
ANI-1500000024-REPOWER135812_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000025-DR.BRANDIMARTE-fatt.35_approvato (1).pdf
ANI-1500000026-D.SSA AMBRUZZI_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000027-COOPSERVICE9117034433 approvato (1).pdf
ANI-1500000031-TAVf.314_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000032-d.ALOISEmaggio2015_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000033-CENTROchirurgiaAMBULATORIALEf201500306_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000034-WINDf.7407817176_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000035-avv.BELLOMI.pdf
ANI-1500000038-TOPCARf._approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000039-TCHRf.000544_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000040-THEMIX_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000041-DESENA_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000042-TCHRSERVICESf.000565_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000043-QUERZOLAf.109_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000047-TELEPASS.pdf
ANI-1500000049-WIND_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000051-MCLINKf.109493_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000052-MCLINKf.88508_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000053-OFFICEDEPOT_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000054-COOPSERVICEapprovatof 9117037004.pdf
ANI-1500000055-COOPSERVICEf 9117039325approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000056-SD_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000057-REPOWER_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000058-MCLINK_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000059-LAG.pdf
ANI-1500000059WERFEN_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000060WERFEN_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000063-CENTROCHIRURGIAAMBULATORIALE_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000064-dott.ALOISEemma_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000066-MERCURI_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000067-QUERZOLA_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000070-TIM_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000071LIFEBRAIN.pdf
ANI-1500000072-TC HR_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000073-LAVAGGIO E GOMMISTA_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000075-THEMIX_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000076-EUROMEDecologica_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000077-REPOWER_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000078-SAS_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000079-LAGSERVICE.pdf
ANI-1500000080-COOPSERVICE appr.pdf
ANI-1500000081-COOPSERVICE appr.pdf
ANI-1500000083-TAV_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000084-aloise emma_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000085-centro.chirurgia.ambulatoriale_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000088-lagSERVICE.pdf
ANI-1500000089-FARMACIACAMERUCCI.pdf
ANI-1500000091-LAGservice.pdf
ANI-1500000092-ASSEL_approvata.pdf
ANI-1500000093-COOPSERVICE_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000095-TCHR_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000097-SAS (2)_approvato.pdf
ANI-1500000099-REPOWER_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000001SAS_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000002ACEA_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000004VERGARI_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000005PINTO_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000006COSMOPOL_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000007LAGSERVICE.pdf
ARE-1500000009 OFFICE DEPOT_ARETEIA.pdf
ARE-1500000010 SERVIZI ABITAZIONE_aqpprovato.pdf
ARE-1500000011 TELECOM_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000012 TELECOM_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000013 THEMIX_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000014 QUERZOLA_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000015 DA.CA. ESTINTORI_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000016 COOPSERVICE approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000017-SAS.pdf
ARE-1500000017-SAS_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000018-DR.BRANDIMARTE_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000019-COOPSERVICE approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000020-BRACI E ABBRACCI.pdf
ARE-1500000021-COSMOPOL_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000023-SAS_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000024-MESCHINI_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000025-VERGARI_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000026-AVV.BELLOMI.pdf
ARE-1500000027-PINTO_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000032-DA.CA_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000033-SERVIZI ABITAZIONE_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000034-QUERZOLA_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000035-CERRATA D_approvato..pdf
ARE-1500000036-SECURLAB_approvata.pdf
ARE-1500000037-COSMOPOL_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000038-OFFICE DEPOT_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000039-MONIGEST_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000040-MONIGEST_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000041-COOPSERVICE approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000042-COOPSERVICE approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000043-SECURLAB_APPROVATO.pdf
ARE-1500000044-MESCHINI_APPROVATO.pdf
ARE-1500000045-ACEA_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000047-PINTO_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000050-VERGARI_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000052-QUERZOLA_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000053-CONTI ROSELLA_approvato.pdf.pdf
ARE-1500000057-DE SENA_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000058-SERVIZI ABITAZIONE_approvato.pdf
ARE-1500000059-SECURLAB_approvato.pdf
ARE_1500000048_TELECOM_approvato.pdf
ARE_1500000049_TELECOM_approvato.pdf
ARE_1500000144_CERRATA D..pdf
BIO_1500000048_GIROLAMO LUCIANA_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000049_SPORTELLI MARIO_APPROVATO20150505_10081133.pdf
BIO_1500000050_LEGROTTAGLIE BENEDETTO_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000051_ANTIFORTUNISTICA MERIDIONALE_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000052_SAIL_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000053_SAIL_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000056_PRONTO UFFICIO_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000057_H3G SPA_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000060_RITELLA BENEDETTA_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000061_POSTA 7_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000062_POSTASETTESAS_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000063_PIGNATELLI_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000064_DIALINE SRL_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000065_L2 SRL SRL_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000066_FARMACIA TREROTOLI_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000067_FARMACIA TREROTOLI_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000068_BIOGROUP_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000069_VITO RINALDI_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000070_EUROCOMPUTERS_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000071_SERVIZI DIAGNOSTICI_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000072_SERVIZI DIAGNOSTICI_APPROVATO.pdf
BIO_1500000073_SERVIZI DIAGNOSTICI_APPROVATO.pdf
```

Comment: 1) Do you need to keep the unsorted list of files? If not, it's more efficient to sort the list in place with the `.sort` method, rather than calling the `sorted` function. 2) Is the common part of the name _always_ after the last `-` or `_` and before the dot?

Comment: 1) I'd like Python to move each bunch of common files to the newly created folder named after this CommonPart. 2)This common part is always after the second delimiter, but after this part may be more delimited parts

Comment: Let's just focus on getting the sorting working correctly. Creating folders and moving files to them is quite straight-forward, but if you need help on that aspect you should probably ask about that in a new question (once the sorting is fixed). SO questions should ideally only contain one problem - that makes it easier for answerers to focus on a single issue, and it also maximizes the usefulness of your question for future readers.

Comment: Sure, i just answered your question if i need to keep the unsorted files. I need these files to be sorted. Concerning this .sort() method - i'm not sure about it syntax. It just sorts the files alphabetically by the first letters in name....

Comment: Ok. The syntax for `list.sort` is almost identical to that of `sorted` except that you don't supply the list to be sorted as an arg. So `files_result = sorted(files_result, key=keyfunction)` is equivalent to `files_result.sort(key=keyfunction)`. In fact, `sorted` works internally by copying the list (or other iterable) to a new list and then calling `.sort` on that new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below *should* sort the full filenames correctly, assuming that your  updated code, (which is based on the code in salomonderossi's and Byte Commander's answers), does show the correct common filename parts.

Note that this code is untested. It would have been easier for us to write answers if you'd supplied a small set of typical filenames in your question. Not only would that have helped us to understand the task better it would also have made it easier to test our code.

```
import os
import fnmatch

files_result = []
for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(r'C:\PATH\TESTT'):
    for fn in fnmatch.filter(files, '*0000*.pdf'):
        if fn.count("-") + fn.count("_") == 2:
            print(fn)
            files_result.append(os.path.join(root, fn))

files_result.sort(key=lambda fn: fn.replace("_", "-").split("-")[2])
print("\nSorted")
for fn in files_result:
    print(fn)
```

If you change

```
if fn.count("-") + fn.count("_") == 2:
```

to

```
if fn.count("-") + fn.count("_") >= 2:
```

then it will handle names with 2 or more delimiters.

---

If you also need to treat a *single* space as a delimiter equivalent to `-` or `_` you can do it like this:

```
import os
import fnmatch

files_result = []
for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(r'C:\PATH\TESTT'):
    for fn in fnmatch.filter(files, '*0000*.pdf'):
        if fn.count("-") + fn.count("_") + fn.count(" ") >= 2:
            print(fn)
            files_result.append(os.path.join(root, fn))

files_result.sort(key=lambda fn: fn.replace("_", "-").replace(" ", "-").split("-")[2])
print("\nsorted")
for fn in files_result:
    print(fn)
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the same name for your result array and os.walk (`files`). Here is your code with corrected variable names:

```
import os
import fnmatch

files_result = []
for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(r'C:\PATH\TESTT'):
    for f in fnmatch.filter(files, '*0000*.pdf'):
        print(f)
        files_result.append(os.path.join(root, f))

#sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: x.split('-')[1])
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: x.replace("_", "-").split('-')[1])  # as Byte Commander suggested
print(sorted_files)
```

And as Byte Commander suggested. The replacement with underscore

Answer (score 1):

I assume this error happens on files where the name parts are not separated by `-` but `_`.

Therefore simply replace all underscores with minus characters before splitting:

```
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: x.replace("_", "-").split('-')[1])
```

The string conversion is also unnecessary, as you're already picking an element from a list of strings, so it can't be anything else.

---

**Update:**

To exclude filenames that do not contain exactly two delimiter characters ("-" or "_"), I suggest the following filtered generator expression:

```
sorted_files = sorted( f.replace("_", "-").split("-")[2] 
                       for f in files if (f.count("-")+f.count("_") == 2) )
```

Comment: thank you! But i've took the wrong version of my code. this "sort" function should sort the files by the part after second delimiter:[2] (XXX_1500004898_CommonPART.pdf  by the "CommonPART"). So after applying your suggestion and changing [1] to [2], I'm still getting the tracebacks

Comment: Maybe you should add a few print statements for debugging and check whether all your variables hold the correct values?

Comment: @o.kar: If you are still getting `IndexError: list index out of range` tracebacks after making those changes then some of the list items do _not_ have 2 or more delimiters. But as salomonderossi says you **need** to use different names for the filenames found by `os.walk` and the list that collects the filtered filenames.

Comment: @PM2Ring I've caught a glimpse of the files, yes there are unfortunately some, that do not have the second delimiter, is it possible somehow to skip them? (All other advised changes are applied)

Comment: @o.kar See my edit for a way to filter filenames that do not have two delimiters.

Comment: @o.kar And if you wish to allow files with 2 _or more_ delimiters (sorting on the part after the 2nd delimiter) then change the `==` to `>=` in Byte Commander's latest version.

Comment: @ByteCommander: You don't need backslash continuation here (and PEP-8 recommends avoiding its use): the Python interpreter does automatic continuation for stuff contained in parentheses, brackets, or braces.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh, yes. You're right. I'm sometimes a bit confused where I need them and where not...

Comment: @PM2Ring In the main post I added the code i have now and its result, which returns the list with the words after second delimiter. But it doesn't sort this files in soutce folder. Have i done smth wrong, or it's not supposed to do it?

Comment: @o.kar: 1) Oops! You are right, that code prints a list of the modified names, which isn't quite what you want. But at least it should be showing the correct common parts. Is it doing that? 2) We are just sorting a Python list here. It will have no effect on the ordering of files on your hard disk. Generally, it's not easy to change the _actual ordering_ of files in a folder. Your OS may provide you with tools to change the order that files are _displayed_ in but that doesn't really change the order of files on disk.

Comment: @PM2Ring, yes it works good, but the files have also a space " " as a delimiter, i tried to add `elif` to the sorted_files line, but Python says itís invalid syntax... 2) May Windows do it?

Comment: @o.kar. 1) You _really_ should have mentioned earlier that space was a delimiter. It's not good to change a question after people have started posting answers.  But see the update on my answer. 2) No, Windows _won't_ reorder files on disk just because you've changed your sorting preference. That would be very inefficient. All it does is change the sorting key function that it uses when displaying the folder.